# error on override akeneo entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-extensions, akeneo

I try to override the `category` entity of an akeneo project. I follow the doc but always have an error i can't resolve.

added this in `config.yml`

```
-
    original: Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category
    override: MyBundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category
```

in `entities.yml`

```
parameters:
    pim_catalog.entity.category.class: MyBundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category
```

the override, `category.php`

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\CatalogBundle\Entity;

use Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category as BaseCategory;

class Category extends BaseCategory
{
    protected $test;

    public function getTest()
    {
        return $this->test;
    }

    public function setTest($test)
    {
        $this->test = $test;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

`category.orm.yml`

```
MyBundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    table: pim_catalog_category
    changeTrackingPolicy: DEFERRED_EXPLICIT
    repositoryClass: Akeneo\Bundle\ClassificationBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Repository\CategoryRepository
    uniqueConstraints:
        pim_category_code_uc:
            columns:
                - code
    gedmo:
        tree:
            type: nested
    fields:
        test:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
```

Then on the browser i have the following error :

```
UnexpectedValueException in TreeListener.php line 74: Tree object class: Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category must have tree metadata at this point
```

here is the function that throw the exception, it is part of the gedmo doctrine extensions

```
 public function getStrategy(ObjectManager $om, $class)
{
    if (!isset($this->strategies[$class])) {
        $config = $this->getConfiguration($om, $class);

        if (!$config) {
            throw new \Gedmo\Exception\UnexpectedValueException("Tree object class: {$class} must have tree metadata at this point");
        }
        $managerName = 'UnsupportedManager';
        if ($om instanceof \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager) {
            $managerName = 'ORM';
        } elseif ($om instanceof \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager) {
            $managerName = 'ODM\\MongoDB';
        }
        if (!isset($this->strategyInstances[$config['strategy']])) {
            $strategyClass = $this->getNamespace().'\\Strategy\\'.$managerName.'\\'.ucfirst($config['strategy']);

            if (!class_exists($strategyClass)) {
                throw new \Gedmo\Exception\InvalidArgumentException($managerName." TreeListener does not support tree type: {$config['strategy']}");
            }
            $this->strategyInstances[$config['strategy']] = new $strategyClass($this);
        }
        $this->strategies[$class] = $config['strategy'];
    }

    return $this->strategyInstances[$this->strategies[$class]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your are loading parent.

In file  /src/Acme/Bundle/CatalogBundle/AcmeCatalogBundle.php add

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'PimCatalogBundle';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

The above issue occurred due to the DependencyInjection. In order to fix this issue follow the below instructions:

### Creating an Extension Class:

```
1) It has to live in the DependencyInjection namespace of the bundle;
2) It has to implement the ExtensionInterface, which is usually achieved by extending the Extension class;
3) The name is equal to the bundle name with the Bundle suffix replaced by Extension (e.g. the Extension class of the AcmeBundle would be called AcmeExtension and the one for AcmeCatalogBundle would be called AcmeCatalogExtension).
```

**# /src/Acme/Bundle/CatalogBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeCatalogExtension.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\CatalogBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class AcmeCatalogExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('entities.yml');
    }
}
```

*Let me know if you have any questions*